# What percent of users have ever viewed the user profile page?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, users(email_address, first_name, id, last_name) and events(event_id, event_name, event_time, platform, user_id). I want to calculate the percentage of users that have ever viewed the user profile page. I have this code and don't how to continue.

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, COUNT(e.event_id) as num_views
  FROM 
    dsv1069.users u 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dsv1069.events e 
  ON 
    e.user_id=u.id 
  WHERE 
    e.event_name = 'view_user_profile'
  GROUP BY 
    u.id
```

Comment: It's better to provide a sample of your data, but if `COUNT(e.event_id)` gives you a correct number, divide it by the total number of users to get the percentage.

Comment: Is it ok to create another query in select part? Like SELECT u.id, cast(views.num_views as float)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*)
from dsv1069.users u2) AS float)*100.0 as p

Comment: `SELECT ...  COUNT(e.event_id)/ (select count(user_id) from users)`

Answer (score 0):

For each user use `EXISTS` to get a `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`, as a result for viewing the user profile page and get the average of these 1s and 0s with `AVG()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT 100 * AVG(
               EXISTS (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM dsv1069.events e
                 WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.event_name = 'view_user_profile'
               )
             ) AS percentage
FROM dsv1069.users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to calculate percentage is to do 2 separate count queries

```sql
select 
   100*( SELECT  count(distinct user_id) 
           FROM dsv1069.events e 
          WHERE e.event_name = 'view_user_profile')
   / ( SELECT count(*) FROM dsv1069.users) views_percentage
```

In case of 0 in select count(*) from dsv1069.users this calculation returns `null`